# Laravel. Postgres. The date is not written from the array to the database

Tags: php, laravel

the error I am getting:
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "update_date" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (1, USD, 27.4083, null, t, null, null). (SQL: insert into "uan_rates" ("ratio", "to") values (27.4083, USD))

1. My model:

class UanRate extends Model {

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
protected $table = 'uan_rates';
protected $casts = [
    'update_date' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];

public static function  getData() {

    $guzzle = Guzzle::getRemoteDate();

    //Iterating over the JSON array received from the API
    foreach ( $guzzle as $value ) {
        foreach ( $value as $item ) {
            $to = $item['cc'];
            $ratio = $item['rate'];
            $update_date = $item['exchangedate'];
            $d = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $update_date ) );
            $update = true;

            $checkDate = date( 'Y-m-d' );
            if ( $checkDate != $d ) $update = false;

            //Database entry
            \DB::table( 'uan_rates' )
            ->updateOrInsert(
                ['ratio' => $ratio],
                ['to' => $to],
                ['update' => $update],
                ['update_date' => $d]
            );

            continue;

        }

        continue;

    }

}
```

}

2.My migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('uan_rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('to')->nullable();
        $table->float('ratio');
        $table->date('update_date');
        $table->boolean('update')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Its only insert `"ratio", "to"`,  but not `'update', 'update_date'` you are using query builder not Model. So _fillable_ method is not required here.  Interesting problem. You are using `UpdateOrInsert` but no condition here, so try with only `Insert` method

Comment: It gives the same error, only now the data is not written to "to"

Answer (score 0):

your are using the [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert) in the wrong way ...

> updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
>
> The updateOrInsert method will first attempt to locate a matching database record using the first argument's column and value pairs. If the record exists, it will be updated with the values in the second argument. If the record can not be found, a new record will be inserted with the merged attributes of both arguments

```
 \DB::table('uan_rates')
            ->updateOrInsert(
                ['ratio' => $ratio,'to' => $to],
                ['update' => $update,'update_date' => $d]);
```

so.. if any record in your table (uan_rates) match with ('ratio' and 'to') columns it will be updated the the new values ('update' an 'update_date') otherwise, a new row will be created ...